# No JQuery intellisense in cshtml files in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, asp.net-core

After several hours I can't figure out how to get intellisense working when using JQuery in .csthml files. From what i've read on other posts etc. it should be possible.

My current setup:

- Visual Studio 2022
- ASP.Net Core 7 MVC

I can confirm JQuery is working just fine when running the project.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution from Microsoft, Hope it can give you some help:

> Starting in Visual Studio 2022, for performance reasons, we no longer
> automatically analyze all JavaScript files in your project unless you
> explicitly opt in. You can do this by unchecking “Ignore Source Files
> From VisualStudio Projects” under Tools->Options->Text
> Editor->JavaScript/TypeScript->Project->General, or by adding a
> `tsconfig.json`/`jsconfig.json` file to your project.

Refer to this [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Javascript-intellisense-is-gone-for-Visu/10151882?entry=problem&q=JavaScript+intellisense).

Comment: Thank you so much, unchecking "Ignore source files" was all I needed to do.